# List of strings input in C

Tags: c, input

I want to sort a list of string. To parameter of `qsort()` function is a list of c[i]'s defined as so :

```
    //N is the number of words
    int N;
    scanf("%d",&N);
    //each c[i] is a word 
    char **c;
    c = malloc(N*sizeof(char*));

    for(i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
      char *temp[100];
      scanf("%s", &temp);
      c[i]=strdup(temp);
    }
```

But when I sort the list, the result is wrong.

Precisely to debug, I added this

```
for(i = 0; i < N; i++){
  j=compare (c[0],c[i]);
  printf("%d",j);
  printf("%s",c[i]);
}
```

My input is '4;a;b;c;d' and I get ' 0b-1c-1d1a'

Can anybody help about this?

Comment: Here it is : "qsort(c, N, sizeof(char*), compare)" and "int compare(const void* l, const void* r){return strcmp(l, r);}"

Comment: @hmjd, yes I am using strcmp()

Comment: **the result is wrong** - how exactly? Not sorted at all? Sorted with bad order?

Comment: sorted with bad order, for example if I input '4;a;b;c;d' I get '0,-1,-2,1' !

Comment: So sorry, my copy paste failed !! : here's  for(i = 1; i < N; i++){j=compare (c[0],c[i]);printf("%d",j);}

Comment: please adjust your question with the code in this comments

Comment: your output cannot ever be acheieved with your programm and input. where are the semicolons are changed to commas and your output should be something like 0b-1c-2d1a or so, according to your code

Comment: You're right, the output is indeed 0b-1c-1d1a (too quick copy paste problems)

Comment: I don't know really the rule of stackoverflow, Why am I downvoted ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is incorrect:

```
char *temp[100];
scanf("%s", &temp);
```

`temp` is an array of `100` uninitialised `char*` pointers, there is no storage for a `char[]`. Change to:

```
char temp[100];
scanf("%99s", temp); /* Added maximum number of chars to prevent overrun. */
```

From you comment:

```
int compare(const void* l, const void* r)
{
    return strcmp(l, r);
}
```

This should be:

```
int compare(const void* a1, const void* a2)
{
    const char** s1   = a1;
    const char** s2   = a2;
    return strcmp(*s1, *s2);
}
```

From the C99 standard section *7.20.5.2 The qsort function*:

> The contents of the array are sorted into ascending order according to a comparison
>   function pointed to by compar, **which is called with two arguments that point to the
>   objects being compared.** The function shall return an integer less than, equal to, or
>   greater than zero if the first argument is considered to be respectively less than, equal to, or greater than the second.

Which means that the type of the arguments to the `compare()` function are `char**`, and therefore need to be dereferenced before performing a string comparision.

See http://ideone.com/rUG89 for example.

Comment: Precisely, to debug, I printed this for(i = 1; i < N; i++){j=compare (c[0],c[i]);printf("%d",j);}. My input '4;a;b;c;d' and I get '0,-1,-2,1'

Comment: @hmjd, it seems indeed to work. But I am really a newbie to C, could you explain why it works this way ?

Comment: @user1611830, added quote from the standard explaining this. The reasoning behind it I suspect is that `qsort()` can be used to sort anything, including user defined `struct`s. Passing `struct`s by value could be expensive but passing in the address is not.